# VBS script to open excel to call macro failing

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

Thanks for taking the time to read, very light on programming skills here.  I have a VBS script that opens an excel model that then calls a macro to pull in data from a .txt file.  The macro in the excel runs fine manually, but when using the script it tries to select all files in the windows explorer window.  I believe the problem stems from opening the .txt file, as my two other vbs scripts and excel models work fine when pulling in data from .xls files.

My VBS script:

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'xlApp.Visible = True

Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\xyzpath\model name.xlsm")
xlApp.Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))

xlApp.Application.Run "macroName"
xlBook.Close True
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

My excel macro:

```
Sub updateData()

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

reloop:

Dim ldate As Date
Dim home, myPath, ldatefile, txtfile As String
Dim ldata As Integer
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim lcol As Integer
Dim s As Variant

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Activate

'Determine end of data set
ldata = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
'Determine date of last data set
ldate = Cells(2, ldata - 14).Value
home = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'Check if up to date, if yes then exit, if no then continue
If ldate >= (Date - 1) Then
    Workbooks(home).Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'MsgBox "Up to date."
    Exit Sub
End If

'Specify the path to the folder and open data file
myPath = "\\xyzpath\" & Year(ldate) & "\" & Year(ldate) & " " & Format(ldate + 1, "MM") & "\" & "data" & "\" & "Standard" & "\"
txtfile = "data" & Format(ldate + 1, "YYYYMMDD") & ".txt"
ldatefile = myPath & txtfile

s = Shell("C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe " & ldatefile, vbNormalFocus)
AppActivate s

'Send keys of actions to Notepad
    SendKeys "^a"
    SendKeys "^h"
    SendKeys " "
    SendKeys "{Tab 5}"
    SendKeys "~"
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    SendKeys "~"
    SendKeys "^a", True
    SendKeys "^c", True
    SendKeys "%{f4}", True
    SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    SendKeys "~", True

'Copy and paste required data
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 3, Now())
Workbooks(home).Worksheets("Data").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, ldata + 1), Cells(50, ldata + 16)).Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.SendKeys "{Enter}", True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

GoTo reloop

End Sub
```

So as I mentioned I believe the error lies when using the Shell to open the text file, as when I run the script as visible I can see it try to grab everything in the windows explorer window.  I've tried different ways to activate the .txt window after it opens, but no luck based on google searches. How could I alter either the VBScript, or excel macro, to correctly send the keys to the .txt application and not windows explorer? Any help or input is greatly appreciated, and thank you all for what you do, I've had a lot of sucess utilizing these forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost: Do **NOT** use `SendKeys`.
Second: Do **NOT** use `SendKeys`.

Use the `FileSystemObject` to read text from files:

```
...
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

ldatefile = fso.BuildPath(myPath, txtfile)
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(ldatefile)
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  l   = f.Line
  v = Split(Replace(f.ReadLine, " ", ""), vbTab)
  For i = 0 To UBound(v)
    Workbooks(home).Worksheets("Data").Cells(l, ldata+i+1).Value = v(i)
  Next
Loop
f.Close
...
```

Comment: Fantastic! This solved my problem perfectly.  Thank you for putting this together, I am now able to call the script from Task Scheduler, run the macro as intended, and is faster(and less error prone) than my original process.  I knew SendKeys was a poor approach but was unaware of the FileSystemObject.  Again thanks.